# Slidemenu won't load the first time in JQuery Mobile App

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, apex

I have a Jquery Mobile app with a slidemenu in the global page, and it appears with the press of a button or a swipe on the screen, facebook style. My problem is that the first time the app loads, the menu never pops out, even if you press the button a thousand times. You have to refresh the page and then in works in all the pages of the app for the lifetime of the session. If you logout and enter again, you need to refresh.

You can see a example here:  http://cic-team.no-ip.biz:9090/apex/f?p=112:2  User: Demo Passw: 1234abc

The menu it's in an "After Header" region as a "List: Menu" type with this custom template:  http://i236.photobucket.com/albums/ff289/Best1989/template.png

The button has the following attributes:

```
data-slidemenu="#slidemenu" data-slideopen="false" style="margin-left:0px !important;"
```

Maybe the Javascript or the CSS are not loading correctly the first time, but inserting the menu in other region has not worked for me. I'll gladly read your suggestions and comments.

I'm using Apex 4.2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `class="slidemenu_btn"` this class gets loaded after refreshing the page why have you used this class.

Comment: @KawineshSK Thanks to your comment I realized that the classes for the button and menu weren't loading because I have a condition for then in the Login screen, which is the first page. After login in, they won't load beacause of this: http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/

I changed the condition and they work now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some research I found the answer to my question, please check this:

http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/

The problem was that I wasn't loading the menu classes at the Login page (which is the first of all) and when you actually got to the page where the button and menu is displayed, it didn't load the classes.

Solved the problem loading the components in the first page but keeping them hidden.